# Как создать форму с фото коллажем в python aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, aiogram

не нашел в интернете не чего на эту тему. Сейчас мой код выглядит так -

```
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardRemove, \
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, \
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
import logging
import config
import mes

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
storage=MemoryStorage()
bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
ID_ADMIN = 'ADMIN-ID'

# создаём форму и указываем поля
class Form(StatesGroup):
    FirstName = State()
    Tags = State()
    Tags_supportive = State()
    Contact = State()
    Site = State()
    Product = State()
    Price = State()
    Branch_barter = State()
    Region = State()
    Conditions = State()
    Exchange_period = State()
    Exchange_restriction = State()
    Wishes = State()
    Comment = State()
    PhotoColaje = State()

# class Form_all_aplication(StatesGroup):
#     Aplication = State()




# Хэндлер на команду /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    inline_create_start = InlineKeyboardButton('Создать заявку', callback_data='start_create_application')
    inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    inline_keyboard.add(inline_create_start)

    await message.answer(mes.start_message,protect_content=True,reply_markup=inline_keyboard)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text="start_create_application")
async def callback_data(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer(mes.name_company,parse_mode='HTML')
    await Form.FirstName.set()

# Сюда приходит ответ с именем
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.FirstName)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['FirstName'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Tags,parse_mode='HTML')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Tags)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Tags'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.support_Tags,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Tags_supportive)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Tags_supportive'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Contact,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Contact)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Contact'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Site_message,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Site)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Site'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Product_message,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Product)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Product'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Price_message,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Price)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Price'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Branch_barter_message,parse_mode='HTML')


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Branch_barter)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Branch_barter'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Region_message,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Region)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Region'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Conditions_message,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Conditions)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Conditions'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Exchange_period,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Exchange_period)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Exchange_period'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Exchange_restriction,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Exchange_restriction)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Exchange_restriction'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Wishes,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Wishes)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Wishes'] = message.text

    await Form.next()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mes.Comment,parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.Comment)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Comment'] = message.text
    
        await Form.next()
        await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            text='Отправте коллаж фото',
            parse_mode='HTML',
        )


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.PhotoColaje, content_types=['photo'])
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['PhotoColaje'] = message.photo[-1].file_id
        
        inline_btn = InlineKeyboardButton('Отправить на модерацию', callback_data='SEND_MODERATION')
        inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        inline_keyboard.add(inline_btn)
        
        collaj_photo  = types.MediaGroup()
        for i in range(len(data['PhotoColaje'])):
            collaj_photo.attach_photo(photo=data['PhotoColaje'][str(i)],parse_mode='HTML')
        await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=message.chat.id,media=collaj_photo)
        await bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            md.text(
                md.text('\n<b>⭐️Название компании/имя эксперта:</b>\n', data['FirstName']),
                md.text('\n<b>Категория:</b>\n', data['Tags']),
                md.text('\n<b>Подкатегория:</b>\n', data['Tags_supportive']),
                md.text('\n<b>Контакт:</b>\n', data['Contact']),
                md.text('\n<b>Сайт:</b>\n', data['Site']),
                md.text('\n<b>Услуги/Товары:</b>\n', data['Product']),
                md.text('\n<b>Стоимость:</b>\n', data['Price']),
                md.text('\n<b>Предполагаемая сфера бартера:</b>\n', data['Branch_barter']),
                md.text('\n<b>Регион обмена:</b>\n', data['Region']),
                md.text('\n<b>Условия обмена:</b>\n', data['Conditions']),
                md.text('\n<b>⏳Срок обмена:</b>\n', data['Exchange_period']),
                md.text('\n<b>⁉️Ограничение обмена:</b>\n', data['Exchange_restriction']),
                md.text('\n<b>Пожелания партнеру:</b>\n', data['Wishes']),
                md.text('\n<b>Комментарии:</b>\n', data['Comment']),
                sep='\n',
            ),
            reply_markup=inline_keyboard,
            parse_mode='HTML',
        )

        await state.finish()

if name == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=False)
```